# Unable to change Windows 10 Display Language

Tags: windows, windows-10, language-pack

I have Windows 10 x64 1511 (build 10586.318).  When I go to Language and add (en-gb, de-de) Windows Update is unable to do so.  If I go get the cab files directly and run `lpksetup` I get an error that the MUI is unable to be installed on this computer.  I tried as a local admin.  All these machines were upgrades from Windows 7 in a domain environment.  Only one PC is unable to add display languages, all others seem to be able to do so fine.

I am really at a loss as to why.

Comment: You are not using the current build of Windows 10.  You should solve that problem, the build, is several months old (more the 3)

Comment: It's the latest Windows update is giving. Is there a way to force new builds as I'm still getting security updates.

Comment: Like I said the current build is 10596.4xx I don't recall the exact build, and it's been in the 4xx build block for weeks and there multiple 3xx builds so your system isn't updated

Comment: I now have 1511 (10586.420) and I am still unable to install the languages.  I do not think it has anything to do with builds as even the initial release builds work properly.  There has to be something else at play.  Manually installing fails, and the Control Panel method says WIndows Update is unable to do so.  Why?

Comment: I never said it was connected.  I just point out you were not using the current build.  Typically in a case like this you just apply a fresh image to the problem PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I might have used the wrong language pack from the manual method.  [Language packs from here](http://winaero.com/blog/download-mui-language-packs-for-windows-10-build-10586/) seem to have done the trick when using it with `lpksetup`.  The automatic method I do not know why it still fails, but this works with the build of Windows 10 I now have installed.  It installed it, when I was then able to go into the control panel.

For future languages I will need to do it this way as the control panel method still doesn't retrieve the language pack.